# Creating custom minimap-titles grammar for .tex fiels

Tags: coffeescript, latex, comments, atom-editor

I've recently started using Atom for my LaTeX needs, and so far it's doing really well. I'm using a package called `minimap` to display the whole code as a scrollbar which is very helpful, but I can't get the `minimap-titles` package to work properly. The comments I'm getting are generated with the `\*` `*\` markers as opposed to with the LaTeX comment characters `%`.

How would I go about adding a *.tex file extension to the list of files recognized by `minimap-titles`, and subsequently specify the delimiter grammar for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.
I've added the following code to the `switch extension` clause in the  `minimap-titles.coffee` in lib.

```
when 'tex', 'cls'
  commentStart = ''
  commentEnd = ''
  # add '% ' to the beginning of each line
  art = art.replace /^/, "% "
  art = art.replace /\n/g, "\n% "
```

You can edit the code by going to Settings > Packages > Minimap Titles > View Code.

In the hindsight it's pretty trivial actually.

Comment: You should consider making a pull request so that your change gets integrated in the repo.

Comment: Good idea. Will do.